# When to use Noop command to keep alive imap idle connection

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

When to use Noop command to keep alive imap idle connection.

Can I execute noop command while running idle connection or do I need to execute **done** command  to terminate idle and then use noop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly, you do not need `NOOP` when using `IDLE`.  When in IDLE, the only command you can execute is `DONE`.  You can then immediately go back into a new `IDLE`.

According to the specification, you must reissue `IDLE` at least every 29 minutes, as the server is allowed to close connection after 30 minutes.  However, if you are behind a NAT (especially on cellular networks), you may need to do it more often to keep the socket mapping alive.

Comment: In practise, I've found 15 minutes is enough for most networks, but some need 10 or 5 minutes if the connection is completely idle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using cellular network and keeps stopping after every 10mins.

Comment: Well, there you go.  Use a 9 minute timer to send DONE and reissue IDLE and you should be good to go.